Graphql query to get count based on filter
Hi All I'm new to Graphql Query , I have a requirement that need to get the count from table based on filter
For eg I have a user table need to know count no of male and no female and others using a single query any one please help me out on it
Table structure might be.
id,name,age,gender,class,city,state,occupation

Achieved using aggregate count in graphql query
